# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and AVDepthData.depthDataMap issue

Tags: swift, avfoundation

When AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layer is added for video previewing AVDepthData depthMaps always comes wired but if we not add and lets say we use uiimageview to assign continues vedio frames it appears correct , is any one faced same issue then pls help.

When below code is used :

```
let previewCameraLayer  = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.init(session: self.session)

    previewCameraLayer.name = "Camera_Preview"

    previewCameraLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    previewCameraLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    if let previewRootLayer = self.vwPreview?.layer {

        //previewRootLayer.masksToBounds = true

        previewCameraLayer.frame = previewRootLayer.bounds

        previewRootLayer.addSublayer(previewCameraLayer)
```

depth maps is :
[See how wired it is appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQEte.png)

but if comment this line :

```
previewRootLayer.addSublayer(previewCameraLayer)
```

it comes perfect :
[Same depth map without AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCFCZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please ask specific question and add more details if possible.

Comment: Sure amit I will try my best to detail as much possible.